# regex expression to match a target word if other target word is within 10 words of original target

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in Python that matches the word "attendance" if the word "required" or "mandatory" is within 10 spaces of either way. Right now my regular expression looks like this:

```
re.compile(r'(attendance)\s(\w)\s(mandatory|required)')
```

This seems to be just matching sentences such as "attendance is required" however, it does not match sentences such as "attendance is important. We require you come to class". Any idea how I can edit this expression?

Comment: The title says 10 words but the text says 10 spaces. Please fix the one that's wrong so we know what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* achieve it with:

```
(?:                   # attendance first, then require/required
    \battendance\b\W+
    (?:\w+\W+){0,10}
    \brequired?\b
)
|
(?:                  # the other way round
    \brequired?\b\W+
    (?:\w+\W+){0,10}
    \battendance\b
)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/0ZIVW5/1/).
Problem is, this takes a while to succeed and is prone to **catastrophic backtracking**.

---

To speed things up, you'll need the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which supports atomic grouping (`(?>...)`). With this, only ~600 steps are needed. Consider the following code example in `Python`:

```
import regex as re

string = """
attendance word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 required
required word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 attendance
required word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 attendance (too far away)
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""
        (?:                   # attendance first, then require/required
            \battendance\b\W+
            (?>\w+\W+){0,10}
            \brequired?\b
        )
        |
        (?:                  # the other way round
            \brequired?\b\W+
            (?>\w+\W+){0,10}
            \battendance\b
        )""", re.VERBOSE)

print(rx.findall(string))
```

For a non-regex way, maybe have a look at [**`ntlk`**](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Why is this prone to backtracking?

Comment: @brianhalperin: Have a look at the demo and how many steps are needed to find a match (>20000). Generally, quantifiers inside quantifiers should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Before matching `mandatory|required` repeat "space + non-space" pairs at most 9 times (`(?:\s+\S+){0,9}`):

```
(attendance)(?:\s+\S+){0,9}\s+(mandatory|required)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ApTWde/2